# Alert On input Field click for 3 times in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, input, onclick, alert

I am trying to show alert box when user click on 3 fields in the form. Once the alert box is canceled, three more clicks are required to display alert again.

I am wondering how can I write a function like this.

Comment: One or more click event handlers and a counter variable declared outside the handler(s)?

Comment: @Mike please try the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using jquery.

**Without ID**

```
var counter=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform input").click(function() { 
if(counter==0)
{
  alert(counter);
  counter++;
  return;
 }
 if(counter==3)
 {
   alert("clicked 3 times");
   counter=0;
   return;
 }
  counter++;

  });
});


 <form id="myform" action="/action_page.php">
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
 </form>
```

**Javascript Only**

This version uses javascript only to make it done by using addeventlistener on all text type inputs inside the form so you dont need to use jquery.just replace the script with this.

```
 <script>
var counter=0;
window.onload=
function myFunction() {
var inputtext =        document.getElementById("myform").querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
 for (var cnt = 0; cnt < inputtext.length; cnt++) {
 inputtext[cnt].addEventListener("click", showalert);

  }
}
 function showalert()
{
 if(counter==0)
 {
  alert(counter);
  counter++;
  return;
 }
 if(counter==3)
 {
  alert("clicked 3 times");
  counter=0;
  return;
 }
 counter++;
}

  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What can we do if the form have many elements and we don't have ID's ? is there any selector that can select all input fields and we can then event listener on that selector.

Comment: yes we can bind an event on all input type but problem is that in your case i am assuming that you are waiting for click 3 times on each input so we need to record how many times each input was clicked that's why we need id to track them.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please provide me the JavaScript selector for $("#myform input"). I am not allowed to use jQuery. Thanks for the Help.